# How to test multiple camel contexts with CamelSpringJunitRunner (Camel Integration testing)?

Tags: java, spring, junit, apache-camel, integration-testing

It appears from [this thread](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/CamelSpringTestSupport-with-multiple-Camel-Contexts-not-working-td4854491.html), that it is not possible to run multiple camel contexts in terms of one test that uses `CamelSpringJUnitRunner`.

How could you load one camel context routes to another in order to test them at the same time? This is already not module testing, but still not the integrational one and this is the problem.. The thing is that you need to load several application-context config files from multiple modules and then start them as "one". This may seem a wrong approach, but how could you test real endpoints from different modules' camel contexts?